# Unable to extract processID from GetProcessId(.. hWnd) (pInvoke)

Tags: c#, process, automation, pinvoke, handle

im using the following method

> ```
>     [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
>     static extern int GetProcessId(IntPtr hWnd);
> ```

to try and get the processId for a running process and the only information I have is the HWND. My problem is that it is always returning error code 6 which is ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE. I thought i might change the parameter to be of type int but that also didnt work. Im not able to enumerate the running processes because there may be more than 1 instance running at any one time.

Can anyone see if i am doing anything wrong?

NB: The process is spawned from an automation object exposed to the framework and only provides the HWND property. Perhaps there is another way to get the processID seeing as the code i wrote was responsible for running it in the first place?

My code looks something similar to this...

> AutomationApplication.Application
>   extApp = new
>   AutomationApplication.Application();
>   extApp.Run(); ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the 'AutomationApplication.Application' class? Did you write that? Does .Run() return a PID?

Comment: Its for AutoCad actually so not i didnt write it.

Comment: Well, option, potentially lame, is to call 'System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();' and check the '.Handle' property of each?

Comment: ah ive just had a breakthrough thanks to your suggestion, ive discovered that the HWND property exposes the MAIN WINDOW HANDLE which i can cross check against the process class info. THANKS!

Answer (score 11):

[GetProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683215.aspx) gets the process ID when given a process handle, not a window handle. It's actually:

```
[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int GetProcessId(IntPtr hProcess);
```

If you've got a window handle, then you want the [GetWindowThreadProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522.aspx) function:

```
[DllImport("user32")]
static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int processId);
```

This returns the thread id, and puts the process id in the out-param.

Answer (score 0):

See an [example on Pinvoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/Module32First.html), no need for the `WIN32` call, as you can use a managed API :

> Alternative Managed API:
>   System.Diagnostics.Process class contains many module, process, and thread methods.
>
> For example:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
...
private void DumpModuleInfo(IntPtr hProcess)
{
    uint pid = GetProcessId(hProcess);
    foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        if (proc.Id == pid)
        {
            foreach (ProcessModule pm in proc.Modules)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0:X8} {1:X8} {2:X8} {3}", (int)pm.BaseAddress,
                (int)pm.EntryPointAddress, (int)pm.BaseAddress + pm.ModuleMemorySize, pm.ModuleName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you **really** think this double-nested loop on all system processes is better than win32 call?

Comment: Pointing to a possibility. Start at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368802/what-is-the-difference-in-managed-and-unmanaged-code-memory-and-size and do some research. Always measure the parameters that are important for the specific case (readability, speed, memory footprint, ...).