# What is the difference in managed and unmanaged code, memory and size?

Tags: c#, .net, unmanaged, managed

After seeing and listening a lot regarding managed and unmanaged code, and knowing the only difference is that managed is about CLR and un-managed is outside of the CLR, it makes me really curious to know it in detail. What is it all about, managed and unmanaged code, memory and size?

How can code I write in C# be unmanaged while this is C# code and how does a memory of size becomes unmanaged. An example and a little insight would be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is managed/unmanaged code in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334326/what-is-managed-unmanaged-code-in-c)

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Short answer:

- **Managed code** is .NET code (VB.NET, C# etc.) that you write and compile to .NET [CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language).
- **Unmanaged code** is code that is not under .NET that compiles to direct machine code.

Long answer:

### What Is Managed Code?

Managed Code is what Visual Basic .NET and C# compilers create. It compiles to Intermediate Language (IL), not to machine code that could run directly on your computer. The CIL is kept in a file called an assembly, along with metadata that describes the classes, methods, and attributes (such as security requirements) of the code you've created. This assembly is the one-stop-shopping unit of deployment in the .NET world. You copy it to another server to deploy the assembly there—and often that copying is the only step required in the deployment.

Managed code runs in the Common Language Runtime. The runtime offers a wide variety of services to your running code. In the usual course of events, it first loads and verifies the assembly to make sure the CIL is okay. Then, just in time, as methods are called, the runtime arranges for them to be compiled to machine code suitable for the machine the assembly is running on, and caches this machine code to be used the next time the method is called. (This is called Just In Time, or JIT compiling, or often just Jitting.)

As the assembly runs, the runtime continues to provide services such as security, memory management, threading, and the like. The application is managed by the runtime.

Visual Basic .NET and C# can produce only managed code. If you're working with those applications, you are making managed code. Visual C++ .NET can produce managed code if you like: When you create a project, select one of the application types whose name starts with .Managed., such as .Managed C++ application..

### What Is Unmanaged Code?

Unmanaged code is what you use to make before Visual Studio .NET 2002 was released. Visual Basic 6, Visual C++ 6, heck, even that 15-year old C compiler you may still have kicking around on your hard drive all produced unmanaged code. It compiled directly to machine code that ran on the machine where you compiled it—and on other machines as long as they had the same chip, or nearly the same. It didn't get services such as security or memory management from an invisible runtime; it got them from the operating system. And importantly, it got them from the operating system explicitly, by asking for them, usually by calling an API provided in the Windows SDK. More recent unmanaged applications got operating system services through COM calls.

Unlike the other Microsoft languages in Visual Studio, Visual C++ can create unmanaged applications. When you create a project and select an application type whose name starts with MFC, ATL, or Win32, you're creating an unmanaged application.

This can lead to some confusion: When you create a .Managed C++ application., the build product is an assembly of CIL with an .exe extension. When you create an MFC application, the build product is a Windows executable file of native code, also with an .exe extension. The internal layout of the two files is utterly different. You can use the Intermediate Language Disassembler, ildasm, to look inside an assembly and see the metadata and CIL. Try pointing ildasm at an unmanaged exe and you'll be told it has no valid CLR (Common Language Runtime) header and can't be disassembled—Same extension, completely different files.

### What about Native Code?

The phrase native code is used in two contexts. Many people use it as a synonym for unmanaged code: code built with an older tool, or deliberately chosen in Visual C++, that does not run in the runtime, but instead runs natively on the machine. This might be a complete application, or it might be a COM component or DLL that is being called from managed code using COM Interop or PInvoke, two powerful tools that make sure you can use your old code when you move to the new world. I prefer to say .unmanaged code. for this meaning, because it emphasizes that the code does not get the services of the runtime. For example, Code Access Security in managed code prevents code loaded from another server from performing certain destructive actions. If your application calls out to unmanaged code loaded from another server, you won't get that protection.

The other use of the phrase native code is to describe the output of the JIT compiler, the machine code that actually runs in the runtime. It's managed, but it's not CIL, it's machine code. As a result, don't just assume that native = unmanaged.

([Source](http://www.developer.com/net/cplus/print.php/2197621))

Comment: I am still confused with managed and unmanaged datatypes.Do they exist in current .net framework.

Comment: @RajanMishra yes, they exist. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54790777/5757626

Answer (score 8):

This could be a very long answer, talking about the many subtle differences between machine code generated by a C compiler vs the machine code generated by the JIT compiler from a managed program.  Long enough to really require a book, but such books have already been written.  Anything by Jeffrey Richter for example.

I'll keep it short and snappy, because all those subtle differences boil down to the One Rule:

*Managed code is code that allocates memory from the garbage collected heap.*

Answer (score 2):

Managed Code runs in Application Domain and Unmanaged Code runs under process of operating system.

Answer (score 1):

Generally managed code has higher runtime memory footprint than equivalent well-written non-managed (native) code.

Comment: Any example which illustrate the difference bettwen Managed and Un-Managed Code

Comment: Hard to quantify, your mileage will vary :).  However managed code requires overhead.  ex. the runtime has to track jit state, garbage collection, objects have to have meta data available for reflection, etc. etc.

Comment: So how I ll get to know what I am writing is whether managed code or unmanaged code

Answer (score 1):

**Unmanaged Code :-**

1.The code, which is developed outside .NET, Framework is known as unmanaged code.

2.Applications that do not run under the control of the CLR are said to be unmanaged, and certain languages such as C++ can be used to write such applications, which, for example, access low - level functions of the operating system. Background compatibility with code of VB, ASP and COM are examples of unmanaged code.

3.Unmanaged code is executed with help of wrapper classes.

4.Wrapper classes are of two types: CCW (COM Callable Wrapper) and RCW (Runtime Callable Wrapper).

5.Wrapper is used to cover difference with the help of CCW and RCW.
Managed Code
The resource, which is with in your application domain is, managed code. The resources that are within domain are faster.

**Managed Code**
1.The code, which is developed in .NET framework, is known as managed code.
This code is directly executed by CLR with help of managed code execution. Any language that is written in .NET Framework is managed code.

2.Managed code uses CLR which in turns looks after your applications by managing memory, handling security, allowing cross - language debugging, and so on.

Answer (score -1):

Apps Which is directly run under the OS are known as

> > un-managed apps

whereas apps which run under the .net framework are known as

> > managed apps