# error C1189: #error : <thread> is not supported when compiling with /clr or /clr:pure

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, clr, wrapper

I am trying to wrap a C++ library which depends on [libigl](https://github.com/libigl/libigl) and [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) in order to use it in C#. This requires a CRL wrapper class.

When compiling the wrapper, I get the following error:

```
error C1189: #error :  <thread> is not supported when compiling with /clr or /clr:pure.
```

I understand this is a [managed vs unmanaged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368802/what-is-the-difference-in-managed-and-unmanaged-code-memory-and-size) compilation type of problem.

''thread'' is not used in my class but deeper in the Libigl stack.

Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: Uncheck /clr option in compiler (compatibility mode).

Comment: Hi @jdweng, thanks for your reply. I set "No Common Language RunTime Support" in WrapperProject-->Property-->C/C++-->General---> Common Language Runtime Support and got a bunch of other errors : C2871, C2653, C2337

Comment: Well your aren't getting the /clr error any  more.  On one project this year it took me a week to go from VS2010 to VS2013 and get all the options set correctly where the code was running fine on VS2010.  I had three different vendors dll in the project.  Don't give up.  Make sure you are using C-language rather than the default window option for passing parameters from c++ to c#.  It took me a while in VS2010 to get the parameters type correct.  I had to modify vendor c++ source code to change parameter type.