# Get Process id that started using ProcessStartInfo in C#

Tags: c#, process

I need to get process id of the newly created process with help of ProcessStartInfo class
here's my code

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "chrome.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "--app=http://www.google.com/";
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = startInfo;
p.Start();
Console.WriteLine(p.Id);
```

However it return an ID which is not the id of the process chrome.exe process. I have verified the presence of chrome.exe process in PowerShell with different Process ID

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Quick search on stackoverflow-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892268/getting-pid-of-process-started-by-process-start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome will [run multiple processes](http://blog.chromium.org/2008/09/multi-process-architecture.html) with one parent process creating a number of child processes. When you run Chrome from the command line your new Chrome process will most likely communicate with an existing Chrome process (the parent I guess) and then exit which explains the behavior you see.

Comment: A quick trip to Task Manager will verify this.