# Process ID of process Started by Process Start

Tags: c#, winforms, process, system.diagnostics

I am trying to kill the process by process ID which I am saving when the process start. But the process ID which I am capturing doesn't exists when I try to kill the process from code behind.

This is the code below to start the process and capture the process ID.

```
private List<int> pids = new List<int>();
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pids.Clear();
            Process myprocess= new Process();

            myprocess.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%SystemRoot%\system32\cmdkey.exe");
            myprocess.StartInfo.Arguments = "C:\\rdp\\RemoteIn.rdp";
            myprocess.Start();
            pids.Add(myprocess.Id);          
        }

        private void terminateAll()
        {
            //foreach (var p in pids) p.Kill();

            foreach (var i in pids)
            {
                Process p = Process.GetProcessById(i);
                p.Kill();

            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            terminateAll();
        }
```

When I click button to terminate the process it shows following error.

[image]

Is there any way to fix this.

After using Palani Kumar code, I am getting below exception.
[image]

Form Looks like this

[image]

Comment: Try saving the Process object in your list, not just the Id.

Comment: Yes, rather than storing the pids, just store the process itself, then you don't even have to call `Process.GetProcessById(i);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting PID of process started by Process.start()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892268/getting-pid-of-process-started-by-process-start)

Comment: @Blorgbeard How do I save Process Object?

Comment: Change `pids` from being a `List<int>` to a `List<Process>` then instead of doing `pids.Add(notePad.Id);` you do `pids.Add(notePad);`

Comment: Side note: there is very good chance that exception tells you the truth - you are launching other process via CMD - so CMD is free to exist after that.

Comment: just use instead of id to process name Process p=Process.GetProcessesByName("YourProcessName");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you are declared pids as `List<int>` and cleared the list (`pids.Clear();`) on button click event. Anyway the below will work for creating multiple processes also.

**EDIT:** As so far discussed with Amrit. The **Windows 8** creating sub processes for mstsc with connecting same domain. So I slightly modified my code.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //pids.Clear();
        Process myprocess = new Process();

        myprocess.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%SystemRoot%\syswow64\mstsc.exe");
        myprocess.StartInfo.Arguments = "C:\\rdp\\RemoteIn.rdp";
        myprocess.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        /* Edit */
        Process proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("mstsc").FirstOrDefault(x => !pids.Any(y => y == x.Id));
        if(proc != null)
        {
           pids.Add(proc.Id);
        }
    }
```

And

```
    private void terminateAll()
    {
        foreach (var i in pids)
        {
            try
            {
                Process p = Process.GetProcessById(i);
                p.Kill();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //throw exception if we close the mstsc manually
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It works like charm if i just open one .rdp file. But when i open another .rdp file it throws above error.

Comment: did you comment this line "pids.Clear();"

Comment: Yes I did comment out the pids.Clear()

Comment: Amrit, now do you have issue with opening more than one rdp files? or just you want to open only one rdp and you are fine with that?

Comment: I need to open multiple .rdp files.

Comment: Hmm... I tested this with multiple and that was working fine. Then try to increase the value in Thread.Sleep and check if the process id match with the PID created in Task Manager.

Comment: Please refer above how the draft form looks like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81150/discussion-between-palani-kumar-and-amrit-sharma).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you hold

```
private List<int> pids = new List<int>();
```

instead of usage just the list of `Process` directly

```
private List<Process> processes = new List<Process>();
```

It's important to understand that the Process object have security descriptor. Everybody can see the existence of the process, someone can open the process for reading information or for waiting for the the end of process. Opening for killing require more rights. The process handle returned by `CreateProcess` have full permissions. So holding of `Process` object used for creating the process gives you such advantages.

I would recommend you additionally to test `HasExited` property of `Process` object before calling of `Kill()` method. One can consider to use `OnExited` additionally (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.onexited(v=vs.90).aspx)) to remove the process if it will be closed by the user. You should call `Close()` method of `Process` object in any way before removing from the `processes` list and consider to use `CloseMainWindow()` instead of `Kill()` method. You should just test both methods (`CloseMainWindow()` and `Kill()`) and to choose the best for your case.