# How to get the process Id safely after process.Start()?

Tags: c#, .net

When a program is copied to many locations and then is started independently, sometimes error may appear:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(exePath);
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.ErrorDialog = false;

Process process = new Process() { StartInfo = startInfo };
bool isStarted = process.Start();
int processId = process.Id; // Failed as bellow When the isStarted is false
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: No process is associated with this
>   object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting PID of process started by Process.start()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892268/getting-pid-of-process-started-by-process-start)

Comment: It's just likely that your process has started, but encountered an immediate failure, like unhandled exception, and terminated immediately. In this case the bool flag for `IsStarted` will be set to false and you don't get process id. If you really-really need this captured, i'd assume you may need some sort of a driver to subscribe to a process start kernel call. You may be out of luck otherwise. In most situations you don't *really* need to capture an attempt to start a process.

Comment: @King Add process.Exited event to get idea when it exited
`process.Exited += Process_Exited;`

Comment: Normally, the Process class should hold a handle to that process. This stabilizes the ID. This should just work. Is that your real code?

Comment: Are you really starting exe files? I don't know how isStarted could ever be false for those. Set UseShellExecute = false.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are starting EXE files you don't need the `UseShellExecute` feature. For some unfathomable reason `UseShellExecute` is set to true by default. Using it entails a lot of complexity.

Set `UseShellExecute` to false and `Start` should always return `true`. Then, the ID should always be valid. Be sure to dispose of the `Process` instance.